# What is the sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{sin(\frac 1 n)}{n}?$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

I want to explicitly calculate the  sum of the following series 
  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{sin(\frac 1 n)}{n}$$
I know that the series converges absolutely because of  $|sin(\frac 1 n)|\leq \frac 1 n.$ I have no idea how to calculate the sum explicitly. Any help will be appreciated .

Comment: It is dubious that there is a closed-from solution.

Comment: I have no idea ...This question came in one exam..@Dr. MV

Comment: @Dr.MV : it involves $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)! (2k+1)!} (2 \pi)^{2k}$ or something like that

Comment: what is the result of $\displaystyle \int_{|z|=1} \frac{z \cos(2\pi /z)}{e^z-1} dz$ ?

Comment: Empirically about $1.472828$ (confirming Claude Leibovici's deleted statement)

Comment: @user1952009 I'm not certain what your comment implies, but that series is no more a closed form than the series of interest.

Comment: @Dr.MV : but it is a 'simpler' formulation, suitable for trying to compute it with the residue theorem, or giving some bounded approximations, and maybe even for saying that 'there is no know closed form'

Comment: By using the Kelvin $\text{bei}$ function, our series is $$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\text{bei}_0(2\sqrt{x})}{e^x-1}\,dx.$$

Comment: Since $0\leq \frac{\text{bei}_0(2\sqrt{x})}{e^x-1}\leq e^{-x/2}$, the original series is positive and less than $2$, but I do not think the original series has a nice closed form. What was asked during the exam, exactly?